# Audio jack not outputing with Sound blaster recond 3Di 14.04

Tags: sound

So I have been using ubutu for a couple week but I keep coming across a reocuring problem of no sound output through my jacks. The internal speakers work and when I am in windows everything works fine. As it states before I am using a Sound Blaster recon 3di. Working on an Alienware mx14 r2

Answer (score 0):

I've known some Motherboards (using Windows 7 here), that need all the 3.5mm audio plugs unplugged and plugged back in to trigger that they are connected.

Comment: I know I tried that.